# How To Write Acceptance Tests for Internet Explorer with: Selenium, PHPUnit and Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, internet-explorer, selenium, phpunit, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to write acceptance tests for a project using multiple browsers. All the tests run fine with: Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

However, I don't know how to run them in Internet Explorer. I use: PHPUnit, Selenium and Mac OS X. I also use VirtualBox with Windows 8 and Windows XP.

I was thinking of running the tests in the virtual machine but I would have to copy the test to the VM and run them from there.

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you have 2 opportunities:

1. To use cloud-based test execution platform which supports Selenium like following ones:

   - https://www.browserstack.com
   - https://saucelabs.com/
   - http://crossbrowsertesting.com/
   - http://testingbot.com/
2. To use the solution with virtual maschine you're already using. Even in this case you can optimize your approach by using specially prepared OS image exclusively for Internet Explorer testing from IE6 to IE11 from [here](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/).